# Put comparison columns into a variable rather than typing out in full in ifelse statement

Tags: r

I am doing an data wrangling with lots of ifelse statements, for example:

```
iris%>%
  mutate(length=ifelse(Sepal.Length>5|Petal.Length>5, "high",
                 "low"))
```

Is there a way to specify the fields I want to compare in the ifelse statement in a variable and then use the variable in the ifelse statement? Such as

```
cols<-c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")

iris%>%
  mutate(length=ifelse(cols>5, "high", "low"))
```

The reason is that some of my ifelse statements can contain 10+ columns and want to avoid typing out all the colnames repeatedly in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset the columns that you are interested in (`cols`), compare the dataframe with the value (`5`), use `rowSums` to count how many of those values satisfy the condition and if there is atleast one value which matches the condition assign `'High'` to it.

```
cols <- c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")
iris$length <- ifelse(rowSums(iris[cols] > 5, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, 'High', 'Low')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify column by its index as well. Would the below code solve your purpose:

```
iris%>%
  mutate(length=ifelse(iris[,1]>5|iris[,2]>5, "high",
                 "low"))
```

Some otherways include:

```
iris%>%
  mutate(length=ifelse(iris$Sepal.Width>5|iris$Petal.Length>5, "high",
                 "low"))
```

Another:

```
a<-iris$Sepal.Width
b<-iris$Petal.Length

iris%>%
  mutate(length=ifelse(a>5|b>5, "high",
                 "low"))
```